# return value Mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, return, mybatis

I'm trying to get a returned value (an Integer value) from a stored function in Oracle 11g.

The function adds 10 to the input number:

```
FUNCTION ADD_TEN(INPUT IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN INPUT + 10; 
END;
```

In my mapper interface I have the line:

```
Integer add(Integer input);
```

And in Xml file

```
<select id="add" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType='java.lang.Integer'>
    {#{output,mode=OUT,jdbcType=NUMERIC,javaType=Integer} = call test_pkg.ADD_TEN( 
    #{input,jdbcType=NUMERIC}) } 
</select>`
```

The call to the method is like:

```
Integer sum = mapper.add(45);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not set property 'output' of 'class java.lang.Integer' with value '55' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'output' in 'class java.lang.Integer'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm really lost with this...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: MyBatis return type must be `void`. The result parameter I was looking for is in the  ResultMap that function/procedure returns.

Answer (score 1):

Why you haven't defined both parameterType and resultType like this:

```
parameterType="int" resultType="int"
```

Remove specific output and try to make it like this:

```
<select id="add" parameterType="int" resultType="int" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { CALL ADD_TEN(#{input, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER})}
</select>
```

Comment: Can we do this in an update  if returning the `count` value after increasing it?